# Angular 2- what is the best way to set multiple components in one path without losing data using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export const routes: Routes  = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'login',component: LoginComponent },

{path: 'main', component: MainComponent ,},

{ path: 'Dashboard',component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            children: [
                { path: '',redirectTo: 'Registration', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {
                    path: 'Registration',
                    component: RegistrationComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'Contact',
                    component: ContactComponent
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
},];
```

How to maintain input fields data in contact and registration component.
With multiple child views the data is lost on moving one child component to another child.

**DashBoard Component 1:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'Registration',
template: `<input type="text" required>`,})
 export class RegistrationComponent{
constructor(public router: Router) {}}
```

**DashBoard Component 2:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'Contact',
template: `<input type="text" required>`,})
 export class ContactComponent{
constructor(public router: Router) {}}
```

```html
 <div>
   <a class="Registratin"  [routerLink]="[':/registaration']" routerLinkActive="active">
                 </a>
   <a class="Contact"  [routerLink]="[':/contact']">
                 </a>
   </div>
<div  class="outer-outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is this related to rxjs and reactjs-flux?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: How to maintain data in components.

Comment: when move to one path to another the first view data is lost @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: What is "the first view data"?

Comment: input fields of form.When i fill my registration form for first view then move to other view the first view data has been lost @GünterZöchbauer. Help me out for fix this.

Comment: I'm not able to find anything about a form in your question.

Comment: I was using ui-router for angularJs and set my all views in one state.!@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127767/discussion-between-hari-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: save the data state of the form in a service and reload

Answer (score 0):

when you route from `RegistrationComponent` to `ContactComponent`, angular destroys the current component i.e. `RegistrationComponent` and then loads the new `ContactComponent`. This is why you lose the input data in registration template.

There are different ways to tackle this:

1.**Use structural directives or [hidden]**
Routing should Ideally be used if your components differ entirely in context. Instead out routing, use ngIf to hide/show the components.
something like ..

```
<Registration [hidden]="id!=1"></Registration>
<Contact [hidden]="id!=2"></Contact>
```

2.**Use Service(s) to communicate data**
a. *Inject service with providers and set/get data to/from service*
b. *Use [Resolve Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) to prefetch the data before navigating*

If you want to dig deeper, go through angular 2 [offical routing example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) which implements different routing behaviours.